# How to apply a python code on rows that are the same?

Tags: python, excel, loops, rows

I have an Excel file containing some data. The first row contains names, some of which are similar.

I want to create a loop in Python in order to apply an operation on each group of similar rows.

I tried this but it didn't help because it shows only one group of my data :

```
df.loc[df['name'] == 'sofia']
```

---

[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rRGg.png)

This is my data it represents the data of a cell of a network
in this very long file like 19000 rows i have the data of each cell for two years 2020 and 2021 and i have to the prediction of the data_trend of the year 2022 so i  did the holtwinters method on one cell only and i wanted to apply it on all the cells this is my problem iam begginer in python so i will be so gratful if you can help me out
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us some example data and describe what you want to do with the rows?

Spontaneously it sounds like you should do something like:

```
def your_func(x):
   your operations
   return results of operations



df['col_to_upd'] = df.groupby('name')['col_to_upd'].apply(your_func)
```

Comment: honestly its just a simple exemple i wanted to apply to understand how to work on the real data i need to work on i will add a comment to explain the real problem

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_functions.html) may be relevant for you to look up the Pandas functions. Like erikheld writes, it is difficult to give an exact solution to your problem, with no data matrix provided, or example of the operation you want to perform on each group.

Comment: Thanks for providing data, I will update my answer in about 4 hours